How to bypass Interceptors for a specific resource in a Ballerina Service?
I have a Ballerina HTTP service with several interceptors added. This service has multiple resources, and for a specific resource, I want to bypass the interceptors.
Is there a way to achieve this without creating a new service to exclude those interceptors?

The Ballerina HTTP interceptors are designed to be executed for the entire service. So currently it is not possible to selectively engage interceptors based on the resources.
